# O que devo implementar para imprimir o nome do usuário em uma saída de dados?

Tags: java

Segue meu código abaixo:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Operacoes {

    int codc, codf, codl;
    Cliente cliente[] = new Cliente[30];

    public Operacoes() {
        for (int i = 0; i < cliente.length; i++) {
            cliente[i] = new Cliente();
        }
    }

    public void cadastroCliente(int n) {
        cliente[n].setCodigo(n);
        cliente[n].setNome(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nome: "));
        cliente[n].setRua(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Rua: "));
        cliente[n].setNumero(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nº: ")));
        cliente[n].setComplemento(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Complemento: "));
        cliente[n].setCidade(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cidade: "));
        cliente[n].setEstado(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Estado: "));
        cliente[n].setCep(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("CEP: "));
        cliente[n].setTelefone(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Telefone: "));
        cliente[n].setDiac(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Cadastro" + "\nDia: ")));
        cliente[n].setMesc(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Mês: ")));
        cliente[n].setAnoc(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ano: ")));
        cliente[n].setDia(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nascimento" + "\nDia: ")));
        cliente[n].setMes(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Mês: ")));
        cliente[n].setAno(Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ano: ")));
    }

    public void mostrarCliente(int n) {
        if (n == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nenhum cliente cadastrado até o momento!");
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                if (cliente[i].getCodigo() != -1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nome do cliente: " + cliente[i].getNome());
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public void apagarCliente(int n) {
        codc = (Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite o código do cliente desejado: ")) - 1);
        if (procurarCliente(n) == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cliente inexistente!");
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Código: " + (cliente[codc].getCodigo() + 1)
                    + "\nNome: " + cliente[codc].getNome());
            cliente[codc].setCodigo(-1);
            cliente[codc].setDia(0);
            cliente[codc].setMes(0);
            cliente[codc].setAno(0);
            cliente[codc].setDiac(0);
            cliente[codc].setMesc(0);
            cliente[codc].setAnoc(0);
            cliente[codc].setRua("");
            cliente[codc].setNumero(0);
            cliente[codc].setComplemento("");
            cliente[codc].setCidade("");
            cliente[codc].setEstado("");
            cliente[codc].setCep("");
            cliente[codc].setCodigo(0);
            cliente[codc].setNome("");
            cliente[codc].setTelefone("");
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Exclusão concluida com SUCESSO");
        }

    }

    public int procurarCliente(int n) {
        int achou = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (codc == cliente[i].getCodigo()) {
                achou = 1;
            }
        }
        return achou;
    }
}
```

Como pode ser visto na linha 37 existe uma saída

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nome do cliente: " + cliente[i].getNome());
```

Porém, esta saída retorna `null`. Já tentei criar um método `getNome()` e adicionar ao final, mas quando a mensagem aparece, quando invoco o método, fica apenas a caixa de diálogo branca. A variável `nome` está guardando em uma String que declarei quando invoquei o método `cadastroCliente`.

Segue minha classe `Cliente`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Cliente {

    private int codigo;
    private String nome;
    private String endereco;
    private String telefone;
    private String rua;
    private int numero;
    private String complemento;
    private String cidade;
    private String estado;
    private String cep;
    private int dia;
    private int mes;
    private int ano;
    private int mescadastro;
    private int diacadastro;
    private int anocadastro;

    void setDiac(int dayc) {
        diacadastro = dayc;
    }

    void setMesc(int mc) {
        mescadastro = mc;
    }

    void setAnoc(int yearc) {
        anocadastro = yearc;
    }

    void setDia(int day) {
        dia = day;
    }

    void setMes(int m) {
        mes = m;
    }

    void setAno(int year) {
        ano = year;
    }

    void setRua(String n) {
        rua = n;
    }

    void setNumero(int casan) {
        numero = casan;
    }

    void setComplemento(String com) {
        complemento = com;
    }

    void setCidade(String city) {
        cidade = city;
    }

    void setEstado(String state) {
        estado = state;
    }

    void setCep(String ddd) {
        cep = ddd;
    }

    void setCodigo(int c) {
        codigo = c;
    }

    void setNome(String name) {
        nome = name;
    }

    void setTelefone(String tel) {
        telefone = tel;
    }

    int getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
}
```

Meu método `main`:

```
class clienteCodigo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Operacoes teste1 = new Operacoes();
        teste1.cadastroCliente(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Apesar do código ainda usar práticas ruins, vejo que você está evoluindo (mas criando novos problemas). Agora comece entender o funcionamento do *site*, como formatar a pergunta, como os títulos deve ser colocados. Veja edições feitas por usuários nas suas perguntas e do seu amigo. Me parece que boa parte deste código não é necessário para entender o problema. Talvez falta o `getNome()` mas não sei, não entendi bem qual é exatamente o problema. Não consegui acompanhar o problema. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Você sabe que só importar o `ArrayList` não faz usá-lo automaticamente?

Comment: Neste caso eu não estou usando ArrayList estou usando só o Array normal, minha dúvida está apenas na hora que vou invocar o método mostrarCliente(); Simplesmente aparece uma caixa de dialogo e não aparece o nome do cliente eu queria saber como posso fazer para mostrar o nome dos clientes...

Comment: Não mostra porque provavelmente não tem. O problema deve estar em outro lugar. Mas erros de lógica assim fica difícil ajudar sem ver o sistema funcionando ou com informações **bem detalhadas** do que está acontecendo. Mas provavelmente se você coletar tudo o que é necessário p/ conseguir detalhar, vai achar o erro sozinho. Você precisa *debugar* o programa. Analisar passo a passo o que está acontecendo com o *array*. Ver o estado dele depois de cada operação. O fato da estrutura do código estar confusa não ajuda muito.

Comment: RRNAN. Eu estou cadastro esses clientes no método cadastroClientes(); que recebe a importação de uma classe que criei chamada cliente onde está localizado todos os métodos e atributos que o cadastroClientes() necessita, editei a minha postagem e coloquei a classe cliente logo abaixo de uma olhada...

Comment: bigown onde eu aprendo a editar minhas postagens neste site? colocar tudo certinho? para não passar mais vexames..

Comment: Estou chamado na minha outra classe chamada clienteCodigo onde eu adicionei o método main importei a classe operacoes e fiz "teste1.cadastroCliente(1);" eu tentei criei por ArrayList e desisti ai esqueci de apagar..

Comment: Coloquei! Rrnan

Comment: Se possível, apague alguns comentários para não "sujar" o corpo da pergunta. Está complicado demais encontrar o problema nesse código, tudo misturado (GUI, modelo, controle)...